# Let R be a prime Jacobson ring (with 1)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, nilpotence

How to show that R has no nonzero nil ideals?

Any hint would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A prime Jacobson ring is necessarily semiprimitive, and the Jacobson radical contains all nil ideals.

Comment: Thank you so much!